# Storing and Searching Protobuf messages in a database

Tags: python, database, protocol-buffers

I have a nested data structure defined with protocol-buffer messages. I have a service that receives these messages. On the server side, I need to store these messages and be able to search/find messages that have certain values for different fields, or to find the message(s) that is referenced in another one.
I have searched on what would be the best way to do it, and it seems having a database that can store these messages (directly or via a JSON) and allow query in them would be a good way.

I searched on what kind of database would provide this support effectively, but it was not very successful.

One way I found was around MongoDB, setting a mirror schema and converting messages to JSON and storing on MongoDB.

I also found the [ProfaneDB](https://gitlab.com/ProfaneDB/ProfaneDB), where the problem [it states to address](http://profanedb.gitlab.io/faq/) is "very much" like what I need. However, it seems it has been dormant in the last 3-4 years, and not sure how stable/scalable it is, or there has been more recent, or more popular solutions for this.

I thought there should be better solutions to go for this use case. I'd appreciate if one could advise what would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should discard the binary protobuf messages as soon as you've  unmarshaled them on your server. Unless you have a legal requirement to retain the transmitted message as-is. The protobuf format is optimized for network transmission (on-the-wire) not searching.

Once you have the message in your preferred language's structs type, most databases will be able to store the data. Your focus would then need to be on how you wish to access the data, what levels of reliability, availability, consistency etc. How much you want to pay...

One important requirement is whether you want to have structured queries against your data or whether you want free-form (arbitrary|text) searches. For the former, you may consider SQL and NoSQL databases. For the latter, something like [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch).

There are so many excellent, well-supported, cloud-based (if you want it) databases that can meet your needs, that you should disregard any that aren't popular unless you have very specific needs that are only addressed by a niche solution.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. For the use case I have in mind, the messages won't be stored for too long in the database, it will be just an interim place where a user can (define) and send a big model in small separate pieces (lets' say 100 to 1000) that  reference each other and on the server side, I need to form a single model by searching and forming the references and probably call another micro-service at the end.

Comment: Also I was somewhat unsure if I understood fully on the binary messages (kinda newbie here!) ; I use python protobuf API to read the messages, and then work with those python objects, I only hoped (or was not sure if it is the best way if)  I would not need to define duplicate structs to work with this data.

Comment: I see. So, if I understand, the client sends many related messages but the server is what assembles these "pieces" into some coherent whole? Depending upon the nature of the model, you may prefer a SQL database as these are inherently oriented toward representing multiple relationships between data. It's difficult though to prove guidance without a better understanding of the data and this isn't the best forum for this type of advice.

Comment: Protobufs use a binary format to send data between machines. This is efficient for transmission but not for manipulation by the machines at either end. This is why you get the e.g. Python objects to use instead. You may be able to just use these generated objects but often it's necessary to convert these into Python objects that you've created that more closely reflect your application.

Comment: We're all newbies at something and this is generally a good place to ask questions